# having problems connecting a bag file with a subscriber - Indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to types of msgs and I am having problems making a connection.

The bag file as this info.

---

```
# from odometry
RaposaWheels track
float32 arm_angle

# from pan&tilt
float32 pan
float32 tilt

# from pan&tilt
float32 body_tilt
float32 body_roll

# from imu
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation

# from relay board
int16 electronics_battery_mV
int16 motors_battery_mV

# from wireless
int16 wlan_link
int16 wlan_level
int16 wlan_noise

================================================================================
MSG: std_msgs/Header
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data 
# in a particular coordinate frame.
# 
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library
time stamp
#Frame this data is associated with
# 0: no frame
# 1: global frame
string frame_id

================================================================================
MSG: raposang_msgs/RaposaWheels
float32 left
float32 right

================================================================================
MSG: geometry_msgs/Quaternion
# This represents an orientation in free space in quaternion form.

float64 x
float64 y
float64 z
float64 w
```

---

Since I had no info I had to built my msg. this is the main msg. Name of the file main_msg.msg

---

```
Header header
tracks track #change????
float32 arm_angle
float32 pan
float32 tilt
float32 body_tilt
float32 body_roll
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation 
int16 electronics_battery_mV
int16 motors_battery_mV
int16 wlan_link
int16 wlan_level
int16 wlan_noise
```

---

The Tracks file is

---

```
float32 left
float32 right
```

---

When I Run the subscriber and the bag file I get this msg.

```
[ERROR] [1530994008.258613410]: Client [/demo_msg_subscriber] wants topic /republished/raposang/telemetry to have datatype/md5sum [pubsub/main_msg/1cb627db77ec9ba82345044061168d5b], but our version has [raposang_msgs/TelemetryOgre/8feb37b7d41c1c54d763ad901a31faa6]. Dropping connection.
```

What is wrong with this msg?
I am using ROS indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296638/having-problems-connecting-a-bag-file-with-a-subscriber---indigo/) by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2018-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-07**:
This looks like your subscriber is expecting a different message type on that topic than is being published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

I only had to respect the original names in the bag file, once I put every thing in there original names, and order, the worked just fine.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) with karma: 61 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0